# Cómo comparar tres caracteres entre sí en C

Tags: c, variables, comparaciones

Una consigna de un problema dice lo siguiente:
"Escribir un programa que permita introducir por teclado tres letras y responda si existen al menos dos letras iguales"

He realizado este código hasta el momento:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
    char a, b, c;
        printf("Ingrese tres letras del alfabeto por teclado (separadas entre sí por un espacio)");
        scanf("%c" "%c" "%c", &a, &b, &c);
        if (a==b || b==c || a==c); printf ("Las letras ingresadas son iguales");
    getch();    
    return 0;
}
```

´
Eso me funciona en una de las opciones, pero existen varias... Que dos sean iguales y la otra no, que todas sean distintas, que la primera y tercera sean iguales y la segunda sea diferente, etc.
Intenté utilizar conectivos lógicos (&& ||) pero no ha resultado. ¿Debería usar alguna función que haga esa operación de comparación? Se que existen algunas pero todavía no se utilizarlas. Me estoy iniciando en la programación en C.
¡Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema pide que se haga un programa que al cual se introduzcan 3 caracteres y responda si al menos dos de ellos es igual.
Se tiene el siguiente algoritmo:

1. Crear variables de tipo caracter y una variable entera que denominamos contador, servirá para saber cuántas veces se repite una letra (se inicializa en cero):

   ```
   char caracter1, caracter2, caracter3;
   int contador = 0;
   ```
2. Pedir valores de los caracteres y guardarlos en su respectiva variable:

   ```
   printf("Ingrese el primer caracter\n");
   scanf("%c",&char1);
   printf("Ingrese el segundo caracter\n");
   scanf(" %c",&char2);
   printf("Ingrese el tercer caracter\n");
   scanf(" %c", &char3);
   ```
3. Hacer las comparaciones necesarias. Si un caracter es igual a otro el contador se incrementa en 1 (bajo la lógica de que cada pareja de letras iguales es una repetición):

   ```
   if(char1==char2) {
       contador++;
   }
   if(char1==char3) {
       contador++;
   }
   if (char2==char3){
       contador++;
   }
   ```
4. Según el número de repeticiones que se hayan contado se elige el mensaje que se quiere mostrar.

   Si se hace una repetición (una pareja de iguales o `contador = 1`), se muestra el mensaje "Hay dos letras iguales":

   ```
   if(contador==1){
       printf("\nHay dos letras iguales");
   }
   ```

   Si hay dos o más repeticiones, se muestra el mensaje "Las tres letras son iguales", debido a que si A = B y B = C, entonces A = C:

   ```
   else if(contador>=2){
       printf("\nLas tres letras son iguales");
   }
   ```

   Si no hay ninguna repetición o `contador = 0` se imprime el mensaje "Ninguno es igual":

   ```
   else if(contador ==0){
       printf("Ninguno es igual");
   }
   ```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!. Voy a probarlo @Hill A me funcionó utilizando operadores lógicos (&& y ||) sin crear otras variables extras (solamente utilizo las 3 de cada una de las leras)

Answer (score 2):

Tienes 2 problemas:

1. En la línea 6 escribiste: `scanf("%c" "%c" "%c", &a, &b, &c);`. Deberías haber escrito lo siguiente: `scanf("%c %c %c", &a, &b, &c);`
2. En la línea 7 después se la sentencias `if` pusistes un `';'` lo que hace que el `printf` se ejecute siempre.

   ```
   int main()
   {
       char a, b, c;
       printf("Ingrese tres letras del alfabeto por teclado (separadas entre sí por un espacio)");
       scanf("%c %c %c", &a, &b, &c);
       if (a==b || b==c || a==c)
           printf ("Las letras ingresadas son iguales");
       getch();
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Tienes razón @germán-martínez, no me había dado cuenta de eso... ¿Podrías revisar este enlace (telegra.ph/Operadores-l%C3%B3gicos-03-24) Allí desarrollé las tablas de Verdad con 0 y 1 de todas las opciones posibles cuando se ingresen los tres caracteres. ¿Sería aplicable a este problema?

Comment: Escribir `"%c" "%c" "%c"` no es un problema porque el compilador fusiona los literales de texto anexos resultando en `"%c%c%c"`, será un problema si lo que se quiere es que estén separadas por espacio.

Answer (score 1):

Declara una variable que sea:

`int totalCoincidencias = 0`

y evaluas cada condicion por separado, sumando una unidad cada vez que una coincida. Te pongo el ejemplo de la primera:

`if (a==b) totalCoincidencias = totalCoincidencias + 1;`

Finalmente imprimes el mensaje si totalCoincidencias >= 1.

Vigila también que has puesto un ; despues de la condición del if y siempre va a imprimir el mensaje

Comment: Gracias @luis-canales. Mira este [enlace] (http://telegra.ph/Operadores-l%C3%B3gicos-03-24) Allí desarrollé las tablas de Verdad con 0 y 1 de todas las opciones posibles cuando se ingresen los tres caracteres

Comment: Esa tabla está cubierta tanto por la implementación que tienes ahora como la que te propongo yo

Comment: Pude hacer que funcione el programa con tu ayuda y la de Germán. ¡Gracias a los dos!

Comment: De nada! Marca como correcta la respuesta que consideres para que pueda servir de ayuda a futuros usuarios. Gracias!